# g/LSB meaning in accelerometer measurements

Tags: accelerometer, register

I am not sure about the phrase I found here:

https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/adxl345-accelerometer-sensor-how-to-use/

> Sensitivity – With the default resolution of 10-bit, the ADXL345 has
> typical sensitivity of 3.9 mg/LSB for default measurement range (i.e.
> +/- 2g), 7.8 mg/LSB for +/- 4g, 15.6 mg/LSB for +/- 8g and 31.2 mg/LSB for +/- 16g measurement range. This means that ADXL345 with default
> 10-bit resolution selected can detect minimum change of acceleration
> of 3.822 cm/s2 (3.9 * 9.8/1000 * 100) for +/- 2g, 7.64 cm/s2 for +/-
> 4g, 15.28 cm/s2 for +/- 8g, and 30.57 cm/s2 for +/- 16g range.

I understand that the value i take from my registers is measured in LSB (least significant bit). So, the minimum i can take is 1 LSB (0x00000001). Which in case of +-2g is: 1 LSB * 3.9 mg/LSB = 3.9 mg = 0.0039 g = 0.0039* 9.8m/s2 = 0.03822 m/s2 = 3.822 cm/s2

Am i correct?

LSB i guess is the smallest value you can measure because its the first (the rightmost bit) of your register
How the 10bit resolution affect my readings?

Answer (score 2):

In ADC or DAC terminology, one LSB is the size of one step that an ADC can resolve or that a DAC can output.  So you can have a one LSB step between 0 and 1, and one LSB step between 254 and 255, or anywhere else in the ADC range.

One LSB is the smallest that a single reading of the ADC can *resolve*, not measure. - If an ADC is noisy, then you may not be able to measure down to 1LSB in a single measurement, but if it's noisy and more accurate than its ADC, you may be able to average multiple measurements *below* one LSB.

Basically, the 10 bit resolution of the ADC affects your reading because, for a perfectly linear 10-bit ADC, there are \$2^{10} = 1024\$ steps between its minimum reading and its maximum reading.  A \$\pm\$2g accelerometer with a 10-bit output is going to have 1024 different possible measurements from -2g to +2g, so -- depending on some fine details in how they treat end points -- one LSB will be exactly, or close to, \$\frac{4\mathrm g}{1024}\$.

As a counter-example, if it were a 16-bit output, then 1 LSB would be \$\frac{4\mathrm g}{65536}\$.

Comment: So, LSB is somewhat like: yourFullScale/steps (like 4g/1024) but because its not exactly the same we use LSB values..

Comment: It's more that it's convenient to use LSB values.  But yes -- if there's any ambiguity stemming from just stating the full range and the number of bits, stating the LSB scaling resolves that ambiguity.